# American Community Survey, SAS EG code for margin of error

Tags: sas, census

The Census Bureau gives the mathematical formula for calculating the margin of error for the American Community Survey, but doesn't include the SAS code for it. The formula is on page 24 of the documentation here: http://www2.census.gov/programs-surveys/acs/tech_docs/accuracy/ACS_Accuracy_of_Data_2014.pdf

Does anyone have the SAS code for the Margin of Error? It would have to incorporate all 80 pwgtp's.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the relevant code. It uses a 90% confidence interval because that is what the Census Bureau uses for their published margins of error on American FactFinder. You can change the confidence interval at the beginning where '1.64537' is.

```
/* Margin of Error 90% confidence code*/

        1.64537*(SQRT(.05*(SUM((SUM(t1.pwgtp1)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp2)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp3)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp4)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp5)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2
            ,(SUM(t1.pwgtp6)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp7)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp8)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp9)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp10)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2
            ,(SUM(t1.pwgtp11)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp12)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp13)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp14)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp15)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2
            ,(SUM(t1.pwgtp16)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp17)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp18)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp19)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp20)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2
        ,(SUM(t1.pwgtp21)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp22)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp23)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp24)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp25)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2
        ,(SUM(t1.pwgtp26)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp27)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp28)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp29)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp30)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2
            ,(SUM(t1.pwgtp31)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp32)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp33)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp34)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp35)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2
        ,(SUM(t1.pwgtp36)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp37)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp38)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp39)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp40)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2
        ,(SUM(t1.pwgtp41)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp42)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp43)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp44)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp45)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2
        ,(SUM(t1.pwgtp46)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp47)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp48)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp49)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp50)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2
        ,(SUM(t1.pwgtp51)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp52)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp53)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp54)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp55)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2
        ,(SUM(t1.pwgtp56)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp57)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp58)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp59)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp60)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2
        ,(SUM(t1.pwgtp61)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp62)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp63)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp64)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp65)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2
        ,(SUM(t1.pwgtp66)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp67)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp68)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp69)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp70)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2
        ,(SUM(t1.pwgtp71)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp72)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp73)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp74)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp75)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2
        ,(SUM(t1.pwgtp76)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp77)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp78)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp79)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp80)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2)))) 
            AS Margin_of_Error,

        /* Plus_Minus */

        (1.64537*(SQRT(.05*(SUM((SUM(t1.pwgtp1)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp2)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp3)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp4)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp5)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2
            ,(SUM(t1.pwgtp6)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp7)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp8)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp9)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp10)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2
            ,(SUM(t1.pwgtp11)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp12)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp13)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp14)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp15)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2
            ,(SUM(t1.pwgtp16)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp17)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp18)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp19)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp20)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2
        ,(SUM(t1.pwgtp21)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp22)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp23)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp24)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp25)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2
        ,(SUM(t1.pwgtp26)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp27)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp28)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp29)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp30)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2
            ,(SUM(t1.pwgtp31)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp32)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp33)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp34)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp35)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2
        ,(SUM(t1.pwgtp36)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp37)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp38)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp39)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp40)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2
        ,(SUM(t1.pwgtp41)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp42)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp43)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp44)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp45)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2
        ,(SUM(t1.pwgtp46)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp47)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp48)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp49)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp50)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2
        ,(SUM(t1.pwgtp51)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp52)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp53)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp54)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp55)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2
        ,(SUM(t1.pwgtp56)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp57)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp58)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp59)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp60)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2
        ,(SUM(t1.pwgtp61)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp62)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp63)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp64)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp65)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2
        ,(SUM(t1.pwgtp66)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp67)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp68)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp69)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp70)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2
        ,(SUM(t1.pwgtp71)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp72)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp73)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp74)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp75)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2
        ,(SUM(t1.pwgtp76)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp77)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp78)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp79)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp80)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2)))))/ (SUM(t1.PWGTP))
            FORMAT=PERCENT6.1 AS Plus_Minus_Percent

/* End of Margin of Error Code */
```

To see where this fits in to a query, here is the full code of a query with the margin of error code embedded.

```
/* Example program */


PROC SQL;
   CREATE TABLE WORK.QUERY_FOR_COMBINEDACS2013_SAS7BD(label="QUERY_FOR_combinedacs2013.sas7bdat") AS 
   SELECT /* SUM_of_PWGTP */
            (SUM(t1.PWGTP)) FORMAT=Z5. AS SUM_of_PWGTP, 
          t1.SCHL,
        1.64537*(SQRT(.05*(SUM((SUM(t1.pwgtp1)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp2)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp3)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp4)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp5)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2
            ,(SUM(t1.pwgtp6)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp7)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp8)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp9)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp10)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2
            ,(SUM(t1.pwgtp11)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp12)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp13)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp14)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp15)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2
            ,(SUM(t1.pwgtp16)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp17)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp18)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp19)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp20)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2
        ,(SUM(t1.pwgtp21)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp22)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp23)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp24)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp25)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2
        ,(SUM(t1.pwgtp26)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp27)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp28)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp29)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp30)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2
            ,(SUM(t1.pwgtp31)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp32)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp33)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp34)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp35)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2
        ,(SUM(t1.pwgtp36)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp37)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp38)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp39)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp40)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2
        ,(SUM(t1.pwgtp41)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp42)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp43)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp44)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp45)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2
        ,(SUM(t1.pwgtp46)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp47)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp48)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp49)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp50)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2
        ,(SUM(t1.pwgtp51)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp52)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp53)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp54)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp55)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2
        ,(SUM(t1.pwgtp56)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp57)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp58)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp59)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp60)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2
        ,(SUM(t1.pwgtp61)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp62)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp63)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp64)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp65)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2
        ,(SUM(t1.pwgtp66)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp67)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp68)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp69)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp70)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2
        ,(SUM(t1.pwgtp71)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp72)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp73)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp74)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp75)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2
        ,(SUM(t1.pwgtp76)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp77)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp78)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp79)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp80)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2)))) 
            AS Margin_of_Error,

        /* Plus_Minus */

        (1.64537*(SQRT(.05*(SUM((SUM(t1.pwgtp1)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp2)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp3)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp4)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp5)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2
            ,(SUM(t1.pwgtp6)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp7)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp8)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp9)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp10)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2
            ,(SUM(t1.pwgtp11)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp12)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp13)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp14)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp15)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2
            ,(SUM(t1.pwgtp16)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp17)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp18)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp19)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp20)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2
        ,(SUM(t1.pwgtp21)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp22)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp23)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp24)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp25)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2
        ,(SUM(t1.pwgtp26)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp27)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp28)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp29)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp30)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2
            ,(SUM(t1.pwgtp31)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp32)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp33)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp34)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp35)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2
        ,(SUM(t1.pwgtp36)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp37)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp38)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp39)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp40)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2
        ,(SUM(t1.pwgtp41)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp42)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp43)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp44)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp45)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2
        ,(SUM(t1.pwgtp46)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp47)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp48)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp49)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp50)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2
        ,(SUM(t1.pwgtp51)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp52)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp53)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp54)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp55)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2
        ,(SUM(t1.pwgtp56)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp57)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp58)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp59)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp60)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2
        ,(SUM(t1.pwgtp61)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp62)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp63)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp64)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp65)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2
        ,(SUM(t1.pwgtp66)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp67)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp68)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp69)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp70)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2
        ,(SUM(t1.pwgtp71)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp72)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp73)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp74)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp75)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2
        ,(SUM(t1.pwgtp76)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp77)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp78)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp79)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2,(SUM(t1.pwgtp80)-(SUM(t1.PWGTP)))**2)))))/ (SUM(t1.PWGTP))
            FORMAT=PERCENT6.1 AS Plus_Minus_Percent
      FROM EC100005.combinedacs2013 t1
      GROUP BY t1.SCHL;
QUIT;

/* End example program */
```

Comment: This may be correct, but it's rather unwieldy. It would be much neater to do this in a data step using arrays.